# How do i change font type for settings.bundle

Tags: ios, plist, settings.bundle

I want to create a acknowledgement section on the settings pane of my app, just like the one that apple created for the Airport Utilities...

I've created a child pane, that links to an acknowledgements.plist already... however, I can't figure out what type they used for writing the actual acknowledgments.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that they use PSGroupSpecifier. http://www.bunnyhero.org/2011/02/14/descriptive-text-in-iphone-settings-bundles/ - this is pretty enough to know.
So, just remove title for group and add footer. All text will be nice formatted as in example.
(Spend over 2h to find any info because my group title was uppercase string)